# Air debug launcher - can't resize windows

Tags: flash, air, adobe

I am trying to debug AIR application in flash cs6 on my 1280x800 screen. The AIR app is for iOS and is 960px tall, so it does not fit the screen.

Is there any way to scroll or resize it?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, increase the resolution of your screen. If not, I would try to run your app in the 3GS simulator, which is half the size but should display about the same.

Comment: I run it in ADL, I see no comfortable way (actually, no way at all) of running it in simulator right from the flash IDE :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and it's really annoying.
My solution so far is the following:

- Decrease the output window size so the ADL window fits my screen
- All movieclips dimensions and positions need to be re-written in relative values (mc.x = 270;  -> mc.x = stage.width * 0.325; )

If any better solution, I'm all ears :)